# Open connection to MySQL from VBA Excel 2007

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc, database-connection

I got this error when try to connect Excel and MySQL using ODBC

> DataSource name not found and no default driver specified

Here is my VBA code:

```vb
Sub test123()

  ' Connection variables
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim server_name As String
  Dim database_name As String
  Dim user_id As String
  Dim password As String

  ' Table action variables
  Dim i As Long ' counter
  Dim sqlstr As String ' SQL to perform various actions
  Dim table1 As String, table2 As String
  Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim vtype As Variant

  '----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ' Establish connection to the database
  server_name = "127.0.0.1" ' Enter your server name here - if running from a local       computer use 127.0.0.1
  database_name = "smss" ' Enter your database name here
  user_id = "root" ' enter your user ID here
  password = "" ' Enter your password here

  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver}" _
    & ";SERVER=" & server_name _
    & ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
    & ";UID=" & user_id _
    & ";PWD=" & password _

  ' Extract MySQL table data to first worksheet in the workbook
  GoTo skipextract
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM inbox" ' extracts all data
  rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
  With Sheet1(1).Cells ' Enter your sheet name and range here
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
  End With
  skipextract:

End Sub
```

I've added references (tools-reference)

The ODBC driver also has been installed.

What is actually wrong? Thank you.

Comment: what is the path to your database? And might I recommend not to run as `root` when you do "anything" on your computer... it is extremely dangerous, and one day it will bite you. Create another user with the right permissions, and no more than that, for things like DB access.

Comment: sorry, what path do you mean?

Comment: Where is your database stored, exactly. It looks like it can't be found.

Comment: the database is in phpmyadmin

Comment: How did you create the database that you are trying to access? It might be worth trying a slightly different approach - rather than accessing an existing database, try to programmatically create a new database with a single table and just a couple of lines of data - see if you can get that to work. Are you using "Option Explicit" in your code? It's great for catching typos in your variable names (although I didn't see any obvious ones).

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles on this site describing similar problems. In particular, there were a couple of pointers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690608/adodb-connection-from-vba-stopped-working) that rang true.

In your code above, one line in particular struck me as troublesome:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
```

followed lower down by

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
```

The second overrides the first in a way that makes me, for one, uncomfortable - although I can't tell you exactly what is wrong, except that you're creating TWO New Connections...

Try that - and the other fixes recommended in the linked article. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help you/others:

Add this reference to your project: Microsoft ActiveX Data object 2 (or any higher version you have)

Throw this code into a module and save it:
Edit the server details in this module.

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Module     : Mod_Connection
' Author     : Krish km, xkrishx.wordpress.com
' Date       : 27/08/2014
' Purpose    : use this for build mysql connectin string.
' Declaration: © Krish KM, 2014.
'            : Free to modify and re-use as long as a clear credit is made about the orgin of the code and the link above
'            : This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
'            : but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
'            : MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
'            : GNU General Public License for more details.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit
Public ConnectionString As String
Private Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002


Public Function GET_CURRENT_DRIVER() As String
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GET_CURRENT_DRIVER
' Author    : Krish km
' Date      : 27/08/2014
' Purpose   : This function returns available mysql odbc drivers found in the registry. You could search by MySQL ODBC and get the first result
'           : but I prefer prioritize the drivers i would like to yield first
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
    If FIND_ODBC_DRIVER(GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES, "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver") <> "" Then
        GET_CURRENT_DRIVER = "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver"
    ElseIf FIND_ODBC_DRIVER(GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES, "MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver") <> "" Then
        GET_CURRENT_DRIVER = "MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver"
    Else
        GET_CURRENT_DRIVER = FIND_ODBC_DRIVER(GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES, "MySQL ODBC")
    End If

End Function

Public Function GET_CONNECTION_STRING() As String
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GET_CONNECTION_STRING
' Author    : Krish KM
' Date      : 27/08/2014
' Purpose   : Returns MySQL connection string
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'        
    If Not ConnectionString = vbNullString Then
        GET_CONNECTION_STRING = ConnectionString
    Else

        Dim Driver As String
        Dim mDatabase As String
        Dim mServer As String
        Dim mUser As String
        Dim mPassword As String
        Dim mPort As Integer

        mDatabase = ""          ' DB name
        mServer = ""            ' Server name
        mUser = ""              ' DB user name
        mPassword = ""          ' DB user password
        mPort = 3306            ' DB port

        Driver = GET_CURRENT_DRIVER
        If Driver = "" Then
            Err.Raise 1, Err.Source, "MYSQL ODBC drivers are missing"
            Exit Function
        End If
        ConnectionString = "DRIVER={" & Driver & "};PORT=" & mPort & ";DATABASE=" & mDatabase & ";SERVER={" & mServer & "};UID=" & mUser & ";PWD={" & mPassword & "};"
        GET_CONNECTION_STRING = ConnectionString
    End If
End Function

Public Function GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES
' Author    : Krish KM
' Date      : 27/08/2014
' Purpose   : Checks in the registry for any odbc driver signatures and returns the collection
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
    Dim strComputer As String, strKeyPath As String
    Dim objRegistry As Object, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes
    strComputer = "."
    strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
    Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes
    GET_ODBC_DRIVER_NAMES = arrValueNames
End Function

Public Function FIND_ODBC_DRIVER(ByVal iArr, ByVal sValue) As String
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : FIND_ODBC_DRIVER
' Author    : Krish KM
' Date      : 27/08/2014
' Purpose   : Simple array function to check if a specific value exists. if yes return the value if not return empty string
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
    FIND_ODBC_DRIVER = ""
    Dim iValue As Variant
    For Each iValue In iArr
        If iValue = sValue Then
            FIND_ODBC_DRIVER = iValue
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Copy/modify this function on your excel sheet button/macro:
update the SQL_GET statement as per your request/sql call.

```
Sub Retrieve_EMP_Details()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Retrieve_EMP_Details
' Author    : Krish KM
' Date      : 27/08/2014
' Purpose   : connects to the database and retrieves employee details.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'

    'Connection variables
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    'Get connection string and connect to the server
    On Error GoTo ERR_CONNECTION:
    conn.ConnectionString = GET_CONNECTION_STRING ' trap additional error if you want
    conn.Open

    'Preparing SQL Execution
    Dim SQL_GET As String
    SQL_GET = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee" ' extracts all data

    cmd.Name = "EMPSearch"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = SQL_GET

    'Execute SQL
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    On Error GoTo ERR_READ_SQL
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        With Sheets(1).Cells ' Enter your sheet name and range here
            .ClearContents
            .CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With
    Else
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = "No records found :("

    End If

EXIT_SUB:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ERR_CONNECTION:
    MsgBox "Sorry unable to connect to the server.." & vbNewLine & "Connection string: " & GET_CONNECTION_STRING & vbNewLine & "System Msg: " & Err.Description
    GoTo EXIT_SUB

ERR_READ_SQL:
    MsgBox "Sorry unable read/wite results on the sheet.." & vbNewLine & "System Msg: " & Err.Description
    GoTo EXIT_SUB
End Sub
```

If you have ODBC drivers installed, all the server details provided, SQL statement adjusted. just execute the sub_routine {Retrieve_EMP_Details} and you should be able to see the results in sheet(1)

Hope this helps and enjoy :)

**Krish KM**